# SQL complex group by field and time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
id  |  game_id | value | create_time
-------------------------------------
1        1        100     1.1.2017
2        1        200     1.2.2017
3        2        34      1.1.2017
4        3        200     1.1.2017
5        1        100     1.3.2107
```

I want to get the all the last records per game_id

```
5        1        100    1.3.2017
3        2        34      1.1.2017
4        3        200     1.1.2017
```

How can I do that using SQL (MySql)?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Of course, I am not very strong in SQL.  I tried grouping by the game_id and max on the date. but couldnt get the other data

Comment: Are you really storing your dates in this format?

Comment: 1. Store dates as dates. 2. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2):

This just requires a simple aggregation by `game_id` to find the latest creation date.  But since you are storing your dates as text, we need to first convert them to bona fide dates using `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT game_id, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(create_time, '%m.%d.%Y')) AS max_create_time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY game_id
) t2
    ON t1.game_id = t2.game_id AND
       STR_TO_DATE(t1.create_time, '%m.%d.%Y') = t2.max_create_time;
```

Note that I assume your dates are in the format of `month.day.year`.  If you are really using `day.month.year` then the format mask in `STR_TO_DATE` will have to be slightly altered.

And please in general do not store dates as text.  As you can see from the above query, it will make your life more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id)
                FROM (SELECT id, max(date)
                        FROM table 
                    GROUP BY game_id) as s2
             );
```

Comment: The max should be on the date.

Comment: You did not specified what "last records" meant... I'm going to edit my answer

Comment: This could return a non latest record whose `id` happen to be the max of another game.

Comment: @IdoBarash check my answer now

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested query to find the last create_time by game_id :

```
select 
    id,
    game_id,
    value,
    create_time
from
    game
    inner join (
        select
            game_id,
            max(STR_TO_DATE(create_time, '%m.%d.%Y')) as max_create_time
        from
            game
        group by
            game_id
    ) as lastGame on
        game.game_id                              = lastGame.game_id and
        STR_TO_DATE(game.create_time, '%m.%d.%Y') = lastGame.max_create_time
```